# how to arrange two items adjacent to each other and one separate?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

$9$ different books are to be arranged on a book-shelf. $4$ of these books were written by Shakespeare, $2$ by Dickens and $3$ by Conrad. How many possible permutations are there if

(a) the books by Conrad are separated from each other?
(b) two books of Conrad are always together?

I want to know how can I solve part b. I have solved part 1 whose answer is

$7P3 \cdot 6!$

Note: I don't just need an answer. I need the idea.

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: About your title:  The second question does not say that the third Conrad book must be separate from the other two, just that two of them are adjacent.  Therefore, you can find the answer by subtracting the number of cases in which no two of the books by Conrad are adjacent from the total number of permutations, as drhab indicated.

Comment: what if two of conrad books are always together and one is always separate? 
SXSXSXSXSXSXS here X represents shake spear and dickens books so it will be 6!. and i have treated two books of corand as a sperate unit and one left as a sperate unit. so my final answer was 
6! * 7*6 *2! =60480 is my ans right?

Comment: @drhab has answered your question.  However, the way part (b) is worded, there is no reason to assume that the third book must be separate from the first two.

Answer (score 1):

**Idea** on b) (that's where you asked for):

You could find out how many arrangements exist in which books of Conrad are *never* together.

In all other arrangements two books of Conrad can be found that are together.

Start with finding out how many sums $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4=6$ exist where $a_1,a_4$  (utmost left and utmost right non-Conrad books) are nonnegative integers and $a_2,a_2$ (non-Conrad books in between) are positive integers. You can use [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) for finding this. First step: find the number of sums $b_1+b_2+b_3+b_4=4$ where the $b_i$ are nonnegative integers.

---

**edit**

If it is requested that in the arrangement $2$ books of Conrad are consecutive and not $3$ books of Conrad are consecutive then we need a different approach.

Firstly there are $3$ ways to select two books. Secondly for the two selected ones there are $2$ orders. Thirdly the two books can be at the left of the single book or at the rigth, so a factor $2$ arises.

Now treat the two consecutive books of Conrad as one unit. To be found is the number of sums $c_1+c_2+c_3=6$ where $c_1,c_3$ are nonnegative integers (they represent the number on non-Conrad books at utmost left and utmost right) and $c_2$ (representing the non-Conrad books in between the Conrad units) is a positive integers. That comes to the same as finding the number of sums $d_1+d_2+d_3=5$ where the $d_i$ are nonnegative integers. With stars and bars we find $\binom72$ possibilities.

Then the non-Conrad books can be ordered on $6!$ ways.

Final result:$$3\times2\times2\times\binom72\times6!=181440
$$

If it concerns $2$ specific Conrad books (so no choice) then factor $3$ falls out and we arrive at $60480$.

Comment: so my answer is 60480 is that right?

Comment: If it is requested that in every arrangement (at least) two books of Conrad are consecutive then my hint can be applied and the answer is $9!-\binom733!6!=211980$.

Comment: no no the question asked in every arrangement t two books of cornad are together and one is always separate?

Comment: Two **specific** books (so selected allready)? Or not?

Comment: any two books can be togather but one should be seprate i.e
CCXCXXXX, XCCXCXXX  XCXCCXXX  here C represent book by Conrad and X represent books not by Conrad. how many such arrangments i can have?

Comment: and they are not already selected any two books can be together.

Comment: Then there are $181440$ possibilities, as stated in my answer.